# Rails: Dealing with child objects on AngularJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs

I'm very new to AngularJS and MVVM in general and was looking for the best way to deal with displaying a model that also needs to display a couple of fields from child model objects on the web UI.

At the moment following basic tutorials my model object in my AngularJS controller reflects exactly my Rails model, and so I can't access fields from my child objects and just see their IDs from the foreign key columns in the database.

I'm wondering what the best convention is for dealing with this situation?

- do I create a [tableless model](http://railscasts.com/episodes/219-active-model) in Rails that contains only the fields needed by the presentation layer. Me defining what the presentation layer needs in Rails seems like it defeats the point of using MVVM.
- do I create something on the AngularJS side that queries for the child objects using those exposed foreign key IDs? If so, how do I optimise it to avoid performing a request for each of my 50 objects in the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah! You should define your api to contain all the data needed for a request. You don't need to create a tabless model for that.

If for example a fetch the json for a Post, Author and Comments json representation also should be there, or at least some part of it.

You might want to take  a look at https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers or https://github.com/nesquena/rabl